# NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, replicaset

I have a standalone MongoDB instance in my AWS EC2 instance. I'm planning to shift it to Mongo Atlas. The prerequisite is to convert the MongoDB instance into a replica set.

Below is the code for my `mongo.conf` file:

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db

#where to log
logpath=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/log/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true


# Enable smaller default file size for MongoDB
# Also reduces size of journal files from 1G to 128M
#smallfiles=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#oplog = 0

# Diagnostic/debugging option
#nocursors = true

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true



setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0


unixSocketPrefix=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp
fork = true

setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0




# Replication Options

replication:
    replSetName: res0

# in replicated mongo databases, specify here whether this is a slave or master
#slave = true
#source = master.example.com
# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate
#only = master.example.com
# or
#master = true
#source = slave.example.com
```

I'm using the below command to create the replica set:

```
 sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /opt/bitnami/mongodb --replSet res0 --bind_ip localhost
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset
```

What else should I change in my `mongo.conf` file?

Comment: any news on this ? I am having same issue running replicaSet on localhost

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue but I resolved following below steps :

I am on Windows server . Mongo DB shell version 3.0.4 . Error in below screen shot same as you mentioned

[image]

So I connect to Mongo shell switch to local .

Use following command. Please note SIR is my replica set name

```
    cfg = {  _id:"SIR" , members:
                 [{ _id:0,host:"localhost:27017"}] 
    
           };

   rs.initiate(cfg)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Or more simply: `rs.initiate()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [bitnami/mongodb](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb) helm chart to deploy mongodb to our custom k8s cluster and got this error when forgot to override `clusterDomain` variable in my `values.yaml` file because by default it was **`cluster.local`** and lead to run `rs.initiate` eval with wrong cluster domain in host address:

```
mongodb 14:59:37.35 WARN ==> Problem initiating replica set
request: rs.initiate({"_id":"rs0", "members":[{"_id":0,"host":"temp-mongo-0.temp-mongo-headless.default.svc.**cluster.local**:27017","priority":5}]})
response: MongoDB shell version v4.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("dc48d2bc-269b-4710-95b8-525b7768fa72") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.4
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node",
"code" : 93,
"codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig"
}
bye
```